# DBCC CHECKDB Corruption in Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search, backup, restore

After some recent server issues, the SharePoint full backup keep getting an error when checking for database integrity. The following error message is thrown in SQL logs:

> DBCC CHECKDB (Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_*SomeGuid*) WITH no_infomsg executed by *DOMAIN\SomeUser* found 216 errors and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time: 0 hours 0 minutes 43 seconds. Internal database snapshot has split point LSN = *SomeNumbers* and first LSN = *SomeNumbers*.

Our only solution up to now is to make a restore of the database (last one yesterday 12:00pm), but before doing so, what are the impact of losing 24h of data in this database? Is it related only to search results? Will a new Crawl refill the missing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing any major impact but you have to run a full crawl after restoring the database.

I think you can create new crawl database and detach the old one then run a full crawl.

if you have too many times then may be a full crawl will take time.

> The Crawl Store database stores the state of each crawled item and
>   provides the crawl queue for items currently being crawled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What would be the best option? I'm pretty sure I'm going to restore, but just to know, would it be better to restore or recreate the DB?

Comment: i think both are Oks  but I will create new DB rather restore. old db may cause some cashing or unforseen issue which are rare but who knows...http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2014/02/adding-additional-search-crawl-database.html

Comment: Perfect! I'll go with the restore & the full crawl as of now since it is the solution which I am the more confortable with, but I'll keep in mind to recreate the DB if any issue occurs later on. Thanks for your help!